# Crear TRIGGER para obtener el último cambio de una Tabla en MySQL

Tags: mysql, trigger

Estoy realizando pruebas con mi servidor local `MySQL` y veo que a veces no se actualiza correctamente el valor interno de MySQL para poder obtener la fecha de la última operación `(Insert, Update, Delete, Create)`

Es decir con el siguiente sentencia de SQL:

```
SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'base_de_datos'
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'tabla'
```

Se puede obtener la fecha de la última operación que se ha realizado en una Base de Datos MySQL, pero mis pruebas no siempre se actualiza a la primera.

Mi intención es crear un sistema parecido usando `TRIGER` que capture cuando haya:

- Nueva inserción
- Actualización de datos
- Eliminación de entradas

**Tengo lo siguiente: UPDATE**

Una tabla `info_db` con los campos

- id => númerico y autoincremento
- table_name => nombre de la tabla donde se ha realizado el último cambio
- last_update => timestamp

¿Cómo armo el TRIGGER?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers para inserción,modificación y eliminación de datos en la tabla `person_table`

Antes de todo crear la entrada para despues actualizar el time_stamp

```
INSERT INTO  `test_realm_db`.`info_db` (
`id` ,
`table_name` ,
`last_update`
)
VALUES (
'1',  'person_table', 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

**TRIGGER INSERT**

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `insert_time_trigger`;

delimiter #
CREATE
TRIGGER `insert_time_trigger` AFTER INSERT
ON `test_realm_db`.`person_table`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
UPDATE  `test_realm_db`.`info_db` SET  `last_update` =  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE  `info_db`.`id` =1;
END#
```

**TRIGGER UPDATE**

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `update_time_trigger`;

delimiter #
CREATE
TRIGGER `update_time_trigger` AFTER UPDATE
ON `test_realm_db`.`person_table`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
UPDATE  `test_realm_db`.`info_db` SET  `last_update` =  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE  `info_db`.`id` =1;
END#
```

**TRIGGER DELETE**

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `delete_time_trigger`;

delimiter #
CREATE
TRIGGER `delete_time_trigger` AFTER DELETE
ON `test_realm_db`.`person_table`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
UPDATE  `test_realm_db`.`info_db` SET  `last_update` =  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE  `info_db`.`id` =1;
END#
```